# InfoPath data disappears

Tags: infopath

I have a created a SharePoint list, then I customized the form using InfoPath.  All looks great until someone uses the form.

1. There is a field Resource Type which is drop down selction, when Contingent Worker is selected another field appears Company Name which is drop down selection.
2. There are three fields that are people pickers Hiring Manager, Service Leader, and Director.

Issue: User completes the form and realizes the information in the Resource Type field is in correct, when changed the names for the Hiring Manager and Service Leader disappear and have to be re-entered.

I have checked the rules on the fields and cannot determine why this is happening. Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Suzanne